# Why my custom post type is not appear in my admin menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types

I've made some custom post types and it's working, they appear in my menu. But now, when I'm creating a new custom post type, it's not displaying in my admin menu. I want to mention that I had installed a plugin (Members) before I created the new custom post type.

```
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'public' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Professors',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Professor',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Professor',
      'all_items' => 'All Professors',
      'singular_name' => 'Professor'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more'
  ));
```

This is working but the next no

```
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Notes',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Note',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Note',
      'all_items' => 'All Notes',
      'singular_name' => 'Note'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog'
  ));
```

> **I also see that it's not created in rest api**

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting show_in_menu? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_menu

Comment: I tried this but it still no working.

Comment: Have you re-saved your permalinks to refresh them?

Comment: Yes, I resaved my permalinks but nothing happened

Comment: If you change `public` to `true` (and resave permalinks of course!), does it work? You obviously don't want the CPT to be public, but this will just help rule out any other problems with registering the CPT

Comment: I changed public to true and resaved the permalinks and it's not working.

Comment: Then its something to do with the registration code, but you haven't shown us all of the code so we are not able to help find the problem. Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code so we can see where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created two post type with same name. And please register all post type after init hook.

```
function add_my_custom_post(){
  $labels = [
    'name'          => _x( 'Books', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'  => _x( 'Book', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'      => _x( 'Books', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
  ];
  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
 );

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
   $anotherlabels = [
    'name'          => _x( 'Pens', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'  => _x( 'Pens', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'      => _x( 'Pens', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
  ];
 $args2 = array(
    'labels'             => $anotherlabels ,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'pen' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
 );

  register_post_type( 'pen', $args2 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_custom_post' );
```

Comment: "*You may have created two post type with same name*" - no, the question clearly shows one name is "Professors" and one is "Notes". Also, this answer does not address the question - it is simply the generic code from the documentation. To be helpful, answers should show how they fix the exact problem being asked.

Comment: I tried this code right now, but it still not working.

Comment: Pardon me, I didn't mean it label, Name means the post type which is in the register_post_type(). May you provide more details like where you call the register_post_type function. You can mail me. I think you may entered same post_type in both register_post_type function.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, and solved it: maybe I can help somebody out with the solution, although it is not at all complicated.

I revisited a course and created a post type exactly like the course example, but it didn't show up in the admin.

The course example worked because it was before the Members plugin was installed, and after the installation of Members, we added the rights for the course's new post type to the administrator role.

So I added the rights for my new post type to my administrator role, and there it was in the admin!

So if you run into this problem, and you have Members installed, be sure that you have added the rights to your administrator role, because that does not happen automatically.